# How Can I Find the Minimum number of stores?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have a list of stores and their inventory and a shopping list. I need to find the minimum number of stores to satisfy the shopping list. I currently have separated the store name to create all permutations of the stores. I am not sure how to actually make the comparison of stores inventory to the shopping list I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def satisfy_shopping_list(shopping_list_json, inventory_json):
    # find out minimum combination of stores that would satisfy shopping list
    shops = []
    print(inventory_json['stores'])
    for item in inventory_json['stores']:
        shops.append(item.get("name"))

    routes = list(itertools.permutations(shops))
    print(routes)



    # if shopping list is impossible to satisfy
    shopping_list_satisfiable = True
    if shopping_list_satisfiable:
        # print out number of stores and corresponding combinations
        # num_stores = 0
        # print "The shopping list can be satisfied by visiting {} store(s):".format(num_stores)
        # for each valid store_combination:
        # print_store_list(store_combination)
        pass
    else:
        print("No combination of given stores can satisfy this shopping list :(")
        pass

def print_store_combination(store_combination):
    store_combination_copy = copy.deepcopy(store_combination)
    store_combination_copy.sort()
    print(', '.join(store_combination_copy))


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    with open(args.shopping_list_json_path) as shopping_list_json_file, open(args.inventory_json_path) as inventory_json_file:
        shopping_list_json = json.load(shopping_list_json_file)
        inventory_json = json.load(inventory_json_file)
        satisfy_shopping_list(shopping_list_json, inventory_json)


def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    p.add_argument('shopping_list_json_path')
    p.add_argument('inventory_json_path')

    args = p.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example Shopping List

```
{
    "apples": 10,
    "oranges": 10,
    "pineapples": 10,
    "coconuts": 10,
    "strawberries": 10,
    "peaches": 1
}
```

Inventory Example

```
{
    "stores": [
        {
            "name":"Kroger",
            "inventory": {
                "oranges": 10,
                "coconuts": 10,
                "strawberries": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Meijer",
            "inventory": { 
                "oranges": 10,
                "grapes": 10,
                "pineapples": 10,
                "strawberries": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Store 3",
            "inventory": { 
                "apples": 1,
                "oranges": 10,
                "bananas": 10,
                "grapes": 10,
                "chickens": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Whole Foods",
            "inventory": {
                "grapes": 10,
                "pineapples": 10,
                "organic apples": 10,
                "coconuts": 10,
                "strawberries": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Kroger 2",
            "inventory": { 
                "apples": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"peach store",
            "inventory": { 
                "peaches": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"CVS",
            "inventory": {}
        },
        {
            "name":"apples r us",
            "inventory": { 
                "apples": 10000000000000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so you want to find out how many stores you have to visit in order to meet the needs of your shopping list?

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes exactly

Comment: we can provide you a naive solution, but this is a variation of a traveling salesman problem which are hard to properly solve

Comment: @aws_apprentice that would be great

Comment: so you don't care if it's a naive solution?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Maybe I don't fully understand what naive means. I guess what I thought it meant was poorly optimized or may not work on every test case

Comment: that's exactly what it means

Comment: @aws_apprentice then yes I am okay with that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough solution from me - just by prioritizing shops that are able to satisfy your shopping list most. Then you just iterate and trim the shopping list from there. I'm leaving the satisfiability check of the shopping list to you. You should do the check before jumping into the iteration I believe, by comparing the aggregate of the inventory against the numbers required in the shopping list.

```
def satisfy_shopping_list(shopping_list_json, inventory_json):
    # find out minimum combination of stores that would satisfy shopping list
    shops = []
    inventory = []  # De-nesting the shops and their inventories. Matched by index

    for item in inventory_json['stores']:
        shops.append(item.get("name"))
        inventory.append(item.get("inventory"))

    # if shopping list is impossible to satisfy
    shopping_list_satisfiable = True  # You need to do this check yourself

    shop_seq = []
    if shopping_list_satisfiable:
        while len(shopping_list_json) > 0:
            # Compute satisfiability score for all shops
            # We assign a score of 1 for each item that the shop is able to satisfy fully
            # Else, we give it a pro-rated score if the shop has the supplies
            scorelist = []
            for i, ivt in enumerate(inventory):
                score= 0
                for k, v in shopping_list_json.items():
                    if k in ivt.keys():
                        if ivt[k] >= v:
                            score += 1
                        else:
                            score += (ivt[k]/v)
                scorelist.append((score, i))

            # Go to the shop with the highest score first
            scorelist.sort(key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
            shop_seq.append(shops[scorelist[0][1]])

            # Update shopping list
            shop_idx = scorelist[0][1]
            to_remove = []
            for k, v in shopping_list_json.items():
                if k in inventory[shop_idx].keys():
                    if v - inventory[shop_idx][k] <= 0:
                        to_remove.append(k)
                    else:
                        shopping_list_json[k] = v - inventory[shop_idx][k]

            for rem in to_remove:
                shopping_list_json.pop(rem)

        print(shop_seq)
    else:
        print("No combination of given stores can satisfy this shopping list :(")
        pass
```